# Ajax Django add button not adding on first click

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, ajax

So I have a dynamically rendered table in Django, the items in the table represent the order items so for each order item I have added to cart, it will show in the table on my Cart page. Now I have a quantity, a product name, order item total and so on. Now I'm using two buttons, add and subtract. **Here's a code so that you can get the idea.**

```
                <tbody>                        
                    {% for order in orders %}
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                        <div class="order-quantity">
                            <span class="order_quantity">{{order.quantity}}</span>
                                <button data-url="{% url 'add' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity plus" id="plus">+</button>
                                <button data-url="{% url 'subtract' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity subtract" id="subtract">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td><img src="{{order.item.product_image.url}}" alt="" width="70" height="70"></td>
                    <td>{{order.item.product_name}}</td>
                    <td> <span>&#8369;</span>  {{order.total_item_price}}</td>
                  </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

Now notice that I have two buttons, each with a data url so that Jquery can make AJAX calls for me to a specified url in Django. Everything is working fine but when I click the add button, on my logs it shows that the item is not yet changed but rather just printed out. But when I click for the second time, the action just takes place, but not during the first click. How to solve this?

**Here's an example.**

```
{"id": 26, "total_item_price": 6000.00, "user_id": 1, "quantity": 4, "item_id": 1, "cart_id": 11, "item": {"product_name": " Nike", "product_date_added": "2021-06-24 09:59:45.449808+00:00", "product_id": 1, "product_image": "nike.jpg", "product_stock_quantity": 6, "product_price": 1500.00, "product_description": "Nike"}}
{"id": 26, "total_item_price": 6000.00, "user_id": 1, "quantity": 4, "item_id": 1, "cart_id": 11, "item": {"product_name": " Nike", "product_date_added": "2021-06-24 09:59:45.449808+00:00", "product_id": 1, "product_image": "nike.jpg", "product_stock_quantity": 6, "product_price": 1500.00, "product_description": "Nike"}}
[26/Jun/2021 22:36:32] ←[m"GET /add/26 HTTP/1.1" 200 371←[0m
```

**Here's my jquery snippet**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("tbody").on('click', '.edit-quantity', function() {
            var quantity =$(this).closest("tr").find("span.order_quantity")   

            $.ajax({
                url : $(this).data("url"),

                success : function(response) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(response.order)
                    console.log(data.quantity)                        
                    quantity.text(data.quantity)
                    
        
                    
                } 
            })
        })

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must repeat your event click into your response AJAX for the new element.
Example :

```
// Event click for the DOM Elements already in your page.
$('.edit-quanity').on('click', function() {
    editQuantity();
}

ajaxMethod = function (url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': token},
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
    }).then(response () {
        // Event click for the new element
        $('.edit-quanity').on('click', function() {
            editQuantity();
        }
    })

editQuantity = function () {
    ajaxMethod(url, data);
}
```

I hope help you.